# How to write a query which is coralated to result of first column?

Tags: sql

On the beginning i will be more happy if someone give me a rod instead of fish while answering this question. Books, chapter in books or sql courses which describing my problem widly will be really appreciate to learn from. 
Okey, so let's started.

I have a table like this

```
assessments (
 id integer primary key,
 experience integer,
 java integer,
 sql integer,
 bug_fixing integer
);
insert into assessments values (1,1,100,100,null);
insert into assessments values (2,3,100,20,100);
insert into assessments values (3,5,100,100,null);
insert into assessments values (4,5,null,100,null);
insert into assessments values (5,5,500,100,null);
```

and here's my queries:

```
select experience from assessments 
group by experience 
order by experience desc;

select count (experience) as max from assessments
where sql = 100 or sql = null 
and java = 100 or java = null
and bug_fixing = 100 or bug_fixing = null
group by experience 
order by experience desc;

select count( experience) as counter
from assessments 
group by experience 
order by experience desc;
```

Second query return not exactly what i want. It should be 2 , 1, 0 instead of 2,1 .
How to combine it in one query?

Comment: You can't use`=` to compare NULL values. e.g. `sql = null` should be `sql is null`.

Answer (score 0):

This logic:

```
where sql = 100 or sql = null 
and java = 100 or java = null
and bug_fixing = 100 or bug_fixing = null
```

does not come close to doing what you intend.  You have problems both with `= null` (which always evaluates to `null` = "false") and with parentheses.  I assume you want:

```
where (sql = 100 or sql is null) and
      (java = 100 or java is null) and
      (bug_fixing = 100 or bug_fixing is null)
```

Your version is parsed as:

```
where sql = 100 or
      (sql = null and java = 100) or
      (java = null and bug_fixing = 100) or
      bug_fixing = null
```

Because `= null` is equivalent (in this context) to "false", this is really just:

```
where sql = 100
```